# jquery text area resize won't work in combination with jquery div content change on radiobutton click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

for automatic resizing of my textarea's i use :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.normal').autosize();
        $('.animated').autosize({append: "\n"});
    });
</script>
```

and for changing the content of a div on radiobutton click i use :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=content_type]').on('change', function(){
        var n = $(this).val();

        if(n == 1)
        {
            $('#postform').html("<textarea class=\"animated\"></textarea>");
        }else if(n == 2)
        {
            $('#postform').html("<textarea class=\"animated\"></textarea>");
        }else if(n == 3)
        {
            $('#postform').html("<textarea class=\"animated\"></textarea>");
        }

    });
});
```

this is the HTML :

```
<form id="postform" name="post" action="phpfiles/post.php" method="POST">

    <b>Regular Post</br></br></b>

    <textarea class='animated1' name="Message" placeholder="Enter your post." maxlength="5000"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="1">
    <button type="submit" class="postbutton">Click here to Post.</button>

</form>

<div class="radiobuttons">
    <div class="text"><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='1' checked />&nbsp;Text Post</div>
    <div class="text"><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='2' />&nbsp;Video or image</div>
    <div class="text"><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='3' />&nbsp;Youtube video</div>
</div>
```

If i refresh the page and enter some text in the textarea it is working as intended and the textarea sizes to the height of the text. Now if i click on 1 of the 3 radio buttons it changes the div's content but the resizing stops to work.

how do you fix that?

Comment: try reapplying the `$('.animated').autosize({append: "\n"});`, it's just done ***once*** when the page is loaded.

Comment: great that worked , could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact your `textarea` can resize because of the plugin you're using. You've just set up the `autosize` ***once*** when the page is loaded. After changing the whole content of `#postform` with a new `textarea`, you should reapply the `autosize` to it:

```
$('.animated').autosize({append: "\n"});
```